# Cannot receive HTTP notifications from eBay in AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, ebay-api

I'm trying to configure the [eBay Notifications API](https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/guides/ebayfeatures/Notifications/Notifications.html) to send notifications to an AWS API Gateway I created.  I already confirmed the API Gateway can receive POST HTTP requests without authentication using cURL commands sent from multiple sources and IPs, so that is not the issue.

Here's what I've set using [SetNotificationPreferences](https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/Reference/eBay/SetNotificationPreferences.html):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SetNotificationPreferencesRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <!-- Use the Developer portal or the <ApplicationDeliveryPreferences> container to set the Application delivery settings -->
    <RequesterCredentials>
        <eBayAuthToken>{token_here}</eBayAuthToken>
    </RequesterCredentials>
    <ErrorLanguage>en_US</ErrorLanguage>
    <WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>
    <ApplicationDeliveryPreferences>
        <AlertEmail>mailto://{my_email_here}</AlertEmail>
        <AlertEnable>Enable</AlertEnable>
        <ApplicationEnable>Enable</ApplicationEnable>
        <ApplicationURL>{api_gateway_url_here}</ApplicationURL>
        <DeviceType>Platform</DeviceType>
        <DeliveryURLDetails>
            <DeliveryURLName>Email</DeliveryURLName>
            <DeliveryURL>mailto://{my_email_here}</DeliveryURL>
            <Status>Enable</Status>
        </DeliveryURLDetails>
        <DeliveryURLDetails>
            <DeliveryURLName>Gateway</DeliveryURLName>
            <DeliveryURL>{api_gateway_url_here}</DeliveryURL>
            <Status>Enable</Status>
        </DeliveryURLDetails>
    </ApplicationDeliveryPreferences>

    <DeliveryURLName>Email,Gateway</DeliveryURLName>

    <UserDeliveryPreferenceArray>
        <NotificationEnable>
            <EventType>FixedPriceTransaction</EventType>
            <EventEnable>Enable</EventEnable>
        </NotificationEnable>
        <NotificationEnable>
            <EventType>ItemSold</EventType>
            <EventEnable>Enable</EventEnable>
        </NotificationEnable>
        <NotificationEnable>
            <EventType>ItemListed</EventType>
            <EventEnable>Enable</EventEnable>
        </NotificationEnable>
        <NotificationEnable>
            <EventType>ItemRevised</EventType>
            <EventEnable>Enable</EventEnable>
        </NotificationEnable>
    </UserDeliveryPreferenceArray>
</SetNotificationPreferencesRequest>
```

I also called [GetNotificationPreferences](https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/GetNotificationPreferences.html) to make sure the preferences were saved correctly, and they were.

I am receiving XML notifications at the email address, but I am not receiving HTTP requests.

**Has anyone else successfully configured eBay to send notifications to AWS or other HTTP endpoints?**   I'm willing to change my tech stack, such as set up an EC2 server instead of an API Gateway endpoint.

I suspect that eBay Notification API cannot connect to AWS API Gateway because I've had this issue in the past.  For example, another RESTful API service didn't support the TLS 1.2 protocol that AWS API Gateway requires for connections, but I haven't proven that this is the case here.  I'm going to set up another non-AWS API Gateway HTTP endpoint service to receive requests from eBay to test this theory.

### Update 1

After watching the stack for another 24 hours, I am seeing multiple successful calls from the eBay Notification API through the AWS API Gateway.  However, the number of successful HTTP calls does not match the number of emails sent.  I still have the Notification Preferences set as above, and I'm receiving the number of email notifications I would expect per the number of events I'm observing.

However, I'm not receiving all the HTTP notifications I would expect.  I am not able to identify a pattern in which HTTP notifications are successful, as they include notifications from each of the four enabled Events, comprising of the following SOAP types: `GetItemResponse` and `GetItemTransactionsResponse`.

Note: I have not had enough time to successfully set up another non-AWS API Gateway web server to receive HTTP notifications to isolate whether AWS is itself the problem.  I'm not ruling out the possibility that it is NOT eBay's fault ;-).  I'm open to suggestions on the simplest way to do this task.  I was looking at tools like [Mockbin](http://mockbin.org), but I'd prefer something that uses HTTPS.

### Update 2

I found [Webhook Tester](https://webhook.site) and configured eBay to send Notifications to the custom site.  I triggered a few events in eBay, and I was surprised to see the notifications coming through both the email and the Webhook Tester, but no Notifications came through the API Gateway.  I'm still not sure why the API Gateway is either not receiving or not accepting the requests consistently from eBay.  I'd prefer to keep using API Gateway, but it seems that in a pinch I could use [the code from Webhook Tester](https://github.com/fredsted/webhook.site) to build my own web server endpoint.

### Update 3

On a whim, I changed the **Endpoint Type** in API Gateway from 
*Edge Optimized* to *Regional*.  I triggered a few more events in eBay and also let it alone for 2 hours to capture system-triggered events.  I'm now seeing more and consistent events being sent to API Gateway.  I'm not sure why this change made such a difference, and I plan to research it more.

As a reference, here's how to configure Endpoint Type in a Serverless project:
https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/#configuring-endpoint-types

Also helpful:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-basic-concept.html

Comment: Seems that the eBay API moved to TLS 1.2 back in 2015 from what I can tell. Interested to hear what you discover with further experimentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several more days of watching the requests come in from eBay's notifications to AWS's API Gateway, I'm ready to say changing the Endpoint Type to 'regional' solved the issue.  I can't say for sure why, but I can say for sure that I am receiving all the events I expect to receive.

If anyone has further information as to why this change works, I'm all ears.  :-)

### EDIT

Per the request in the comments, here is the `serverless.yml` file:

```yaml
service: party-light

plugins:
  - serverless-offline

provider:
  name: aws
  endpointType: REGIONAL
  runtime: nodejs8.10
  stage: dev
  region: us-east-1
  memorySize: 128

  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - "iot:*"
      Resource:
        - "*"
    - Effect: 'Allow'
      Action:
        - 's3:PutObject'
      Resource:
        - 'arn:aws:s3:::{MY_S3_BUCKET}/*'

functions:
  party:
    handler: handler.party
    events:
      - http:
          path: party
          method: post
```

Comment: thank you for providing this. Could you please export your Amazon API Gateway configuration? I would like to try to attempt this.